# React native, redux and reselect - selector returns incorrect data

Tags: react-native, redux, reselect

I have the following code:

`select.js`:

```
export const getNavigationRoutes = state => state.navigation.routes
export const getNavigationIndex = state => state.navigation.index

export const getNavigationTab = createSelector(
  [getNavigationRoutes, getNavigationIndex],
  (routes, index) => (routes[index])
)

export const getBackNavSupported = createSelector(
  getNavigationTab, nevTab => nevTab.index !== 0
)
```

`viewController.js`:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import AppView from './AppView'
import { getBackNavSupported } from '../selectors

export default connect(
  state => ({
    backNavSupported: getBackNavSupported(state),
  }))
)(AppView)
```

My state changes from

```
{
  "index": 1,
  "key": "root",
  "routes": [
    {
      "key": "HomeTab",
      "title": "Home",
      "index": 0,
      "routes": [ /* .... */ ]
    },
    {
      "key": "FamilyTab",
      "title": "Family",
      "index": 0,
      "iconName": "people",
      "routes": [ /* .... */ ]
    },
  ]
}
```

to

```
{
  "index": 1,
  "key": "root",
  "routes": [
    {
      "key": "HomeTab",
      "title": "Home",
      "index": 0,
      "routes": [ /* ... */ ]
    },
    {
      "key": "FamilyTab",
      "title": "Family",
      "index": 1,
      "routes": [ /* ... */ ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I use `backNavSupported` in `AppView`, but when I check the value of `backNavSupported` *after* the state changes, I get `false`, which makes now sense to me...

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

This how I use it in the component (maybe scope issues?):

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { backNavSupported} = this.props
    BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
      if (backNavSupported ) {
        back()
        return true
      }
      return false
    })
  }
```

Comment: Your `getNavigationTab` selector has an array.  Should be `getNavigationTab = createSelector(
  getNavigationRoutes,
  getNavigationIndex,
  (routes, index) => (routes[index])
)`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that OK, check out https://github.com/reactjs/reselect, specifically the part about  `Composing Selectors`. anyway, I tried without `[]`  and it did not work either.

Comment: Hmmm, you're right. I've never seen that syntax in reselect before.  I'll take another look to see if I can spot the error

Comment: If you put a log statement in your second memoized selector (`getBackNavSupported`), can you verify that it is getting called after the state change?

Comment: @Kuf were you able to figure out what was wrong?